# Why is -9 base 10 equal to a7ffda89 in base 17?

Tags: c, complement

Using Microsoft's implementation of `itoa`, how do you get "a7ffda89" as the base 17 representation of -9 in base 10? What I am looking for is a description of the algorithm.

Here is the code I used to find out what `itoa` would return using Microsoft's implementation:

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
  char buff[256] = {};
  memset(buff, '0', 256);
  _itoa_s(-9, buff, 256, 17);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It looks like it converts `(unsigned) -9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/):

> If `base` is 10 and value is negative, the resulting string is preceded with a minus sign (-). With any other base, value is always considered unsigned.

Answer (score 2):

-9 expressed as an *unsigned 32-bit integer* is 4294967287. Converting *that* to base 17 gives a7ffda89. As a check, in Python:

```
>>> int('a7ffda89', 17) - (1<<32)
-9
```